# How to avoid the delay of almost 1 second when back button is pressed in home fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have one activity application with multiple fragments, Onbackpressed function is working correctly while I go to the other fragment from the home fragment it's working correctly but when I am on the home fragment and press the back button then it finishes the activity but there is the delay of almost 1 second which is not acceptable, how to avoid it. Here is my back-pressed function.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val count = supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
    if(count == 1){
        finish()
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Comment: get rid of the call to ```finish()```. ```onBackPressed()``` implements it internally

Comment: if I don't call finish then back press function remove the home fragment and show the white screen and then the back pressed to finish the activity

Answer (score 0):

if Activity attaches by default fragment and you want to exit from an application on back button pressed then here is my code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
          int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if(count==1){
                finish();
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
    }
```